# Hooks (useLayoutEffekt) gets triggered too often / values inside Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am having problems figuring out the correct way how to use useEffect / useLayoutEffect.
I have a component, which waits on a pointerevent (`PointerEventTypes.POINTERTAP` (comes from babylon). It is within a `useLayoutEffect` hook. It then fires up `pointerClick()` to do something.
The problem I am having is that there are 2 dependencies I need to watch: `buildings` and `activeBuilding`. How can I achieve that the function `pointerClick()` does not get triggered two times on the first single click?
I think what is happening is that there is one event (PointerTAP) and the function gets called. Then within the function I am changing activeBuilding which then again triggers a re-render and a second run of the function `pointerClick()`.
If I instead use useEffect (not useLayoutEffect) I have to click twice to set the data because it does change the values after rendering. So it's not what I want.

Here is the example code:

```
  const pointerClick = () => {
    if (scene) {
      const pickInfo = scene.pick(scene.pointerX, scene.pointerY)

      if (buildings.length === 0 && activeBuilding === -1) {
        setActiveBuilding(0)
      }

      if (activeBuilding != -1) {
        if (pickInfo?.pickedMesh?.metadata?.measurement?.type === 'handle') {
          handleDeletePoint(
            pickInfo.pickedMesh.metadata.measurement.id,
            activeBuilding
          )
        } else if (pickInfo?.pickedMesh?.name === 'measureOutline') {
          setActiveBuilding(-1)
        }

        else if (
          !pickInfo?.pickedMesh?.metadata?.measurement &&
          pickInfo?.pickedPoint
        ) {
          handleAddPoint(pickInfo.pickedPoint, activeBuilding)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (scene) {
      const obs = scene?.onPointerObservable.add((pointerInfoEvent) => {
        switch (pointerInfoEvent.type) {
          case PointerEventTypes.POINTERTAP:
            pointerClick()
            // setClicked(false)
            break
        }
      })
      return () => {
        scene.onPointerObservable.remove(obs)
      }
    }
  }, [canvas, scene, buildings, activeBuilding])
  return <Measure />
}
```

Do I have to get rid of one of the two: `buildings` or `activeBuilding` as a dependency (what I think I cannot do since I need both values to be changeable). What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you so much!

Comment: There's nothing here that suggests to me that the same event would get triggered twice, because you have a cleanup function which *will* also get called right before every time your useLayoutEffect is called (except the first time) Are you seeing multiple click events?

Comment: React strict mode makes it so that effects run twice . Try removing it from your App.js and it should work as you like it to .

Comment: no there is only on click event. wich is correct. but the it does run the `pointerClick` function two times. first time it starts for example with `activeBuilding === -1`, so it goes to the `if (activeBuilding === -1)` and sets the value to 0. i think that this retriggers the layouteffect and runs the same function again, this time with `activeBuilding === 0` --> so two runs on one click.

Comment: @AlaaEddineCherif i did check that too - it does not make any difference if using strict or not strict mode. so it semms to be the logic behind `activeBuilding` and `buildings` and how i check their state... :/